# Handle Angular 401 responses

Tags: angularjs

I have simple api and a authorization point

when i request to api i get a 401 if the token is invalid (token loses validity past five minutes).

i know i can intercept 401 for example with

```
app.factory("HttpErrorInterceptorModule", ["$q", "$rootScope", "$location",
    function($q, $rootScope, $location) {
        var success = function(response) {
            // pass through
            return response;
        },
            error = function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401) {
                    // dostuff
                }

                return $q.reject(response);
            };

        return function(httpPromise) {
            return httpPromise.then(success, error);
        };
    }
]).config(["$httpProvider",
    function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push("HttpErrorInterceptorModule");
    }
]);
```

but i want capture and queue the request and show a login form if is success then change the token (it's a header) and execute request again

Answer (score 6):

You can use $httpInterceptor in slightly another way. If you want to redirect user after login to page where user actually failed you need to cache failed request in some service and then redirect user somewhere after login (I beleive in logic connected to your login).

But you may need to have some test endpoint to protect your controllers from unrestricted access, you might want to use resolve https://thinkster.io/egghead/resolve/
So in this case you will receive error connected with restricted access to proctedted endpoint but not to your page.

To solve this problem I used marker param (or header) to find out where I should redirect user after login.

Here is example of your httpInterceptor.

```
angular.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $log, someService) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            return config || $q.when(config)
        },
        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                //here I preserve login page 
                someService
                   .setRestrictedPageBeforeLogin(
                            extractPreservedInfoAboutPage(response)
                    )
                $rootScope.$broadcast('error')
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation? and how queue the request

Comment: Regarding the queue of requests I would put them to cache, some object on failed request and then redirect and then retrieve after successful login. I'll fix the answer in 15 mins.

Comment: if i store in `request` function `configs.push(config)` each config and pops in `response` function `configs.pop()`, how can I identify each response belongs to request?

Comment: You don't need to store each request, because you will run out of memory. I would store failed configs, and for each controller I would have resolve section with test request for auth where you could pass information about desired page. 

If this requests fails target page won't be loaded -> you will show your login page and then having information about requested page you will proceed to page.

Comment: Thanks for this! I don't understand why the response can't be handled by the same "response" method just because it's a 401 as opposed to 200

Answer (score 2):

angular-http-auth module provides a service that intercepts requests and queques them to re-send them later once a user logs in.

This service fires also these events below, so you could listen to them and decide what to show on screen

- event:auth-loginRequired
- event:auth-loginCancelled
- event:aut-loginConfirmed

Look at the code. It has just a few lines of code

https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth